# SUMIF formula which includes Lastrow

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to enter a SUMIF formula into my VBA but the range of cells may change depending on the 'Lastrow' on another tab. I'm able to get the Lastrow no problem but the problem is trying to enter into my SUMIF formula. 'Lastrow' value should replace cells Q156 & H156. Hope this makes sense. Any suggestions welcome.

See below:

```
Sub UpdateReconData()

    Dim Lastrow6 As Integer

    'gets last Row on Formatting Spreadsheet
    Sheets("Formatting").Select
    Lastrow6 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Recon").Select

    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = _
        "=SUMIF(Formatting!$Q$2:$Q$156(Recon!$A2&Recon!B$1),Formatting!$H$2:$H$156)"

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't believe you are going to get much more than a `#REF!` error unless you add in a comma between the *criteria_range* and the *criteria_value*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the `Lastrow6` variable into the formula string. You can do this by using the ampersand (&) symbol to concatenate strings with variables.

```
Range("B2").Value = _
      "=SUMIF(Formatting!$Q$2:$Q$" & Lastrow6 & _
      "(Recon!$A2&Recon!B$1),Formatting!$H$2:$H$" & Lastrow6 & ")"
```

Comment: You my friend are an absolute hero!

Comment: No problem - you can also prevent having to select ranges and activate sheets by using: `Sheets("Recon").Range("B2").Value = "enter formula"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your formula:

```
"=SUMIF(Formatting!$Q$2:$Q$" & Lastrow6 & "(Recon!$A2&Recon!B$1),Formatting!$H$2:$H$" & Lastrow6 & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the **lastRow6** is in a couple of places, a [Range.Replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) be easier than a string concatenation.

```
Sub UpdateReconData()
    Dim lastRow6 As Long

    'gets last Row on Formatting Spreadsheet
    With Worksheets("Formatting")
        lastRow6 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With Worksheets("Recon")
        .Range("B2").Formula = _
            Replace("=SUMIF(Formatting!$Q$2:$Q$XYZ, $A2&B$1, Formatting!$H$2:$H$XYZ)", _
                    "XYZ", lastRow6)
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm not entirely sure why you are not using full column references in the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) but I'm sure that there are other rows with data that coulod confuse the result. Full column references do not slow down a SUMIF / SUMIFS the way it does to a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616). Ideally, the  **lastRow6** could be built into the SUMIF formula like the following.

```
    With Worksheets("Recon")
        'never have to do this again.
        .Range("B2").Formula = _
            "=SUMIF(Formatting!$Q$2:INDEX(Formatting!$Q:$Q, MATCH(1e99, Formatting!$H:$H)), " & _
                "$A2&B$1, " & _
                "Formatting!$H$2:INDEX(Formatting!$H:$H, MATCH(1e99, Formatting!$H:$H)))"
    End With
```

The `MATCH(1e99, Formatting!$H:$H)` locates the last row in Formatting!H:H that contains a number. Since you are summing this column, no rows below that matter.